# How to convert checkbox into string value in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, gridview

How can I convert a checkbox into a string value in gridview whilst exporting data into excel using asp.net mvc?

Model:

```
    public class empViewmodel
    {         
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public bool male{ get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> city_id { get; set; }
    }
```

controller:

```
    public ActionResult export1(emplyeeModel em)
    {
        var grid = new GridView();
        grid.DataSource = e1.getlist(em);
        grid.DataBind();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcelFile.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        grid.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return View("export");
    }
```

Getlist method:

```
        public List<emplyeeModel> getlist(emplyeeModel e1)
        {
            var tbl =db.emps.ToList();
            List<emplyeeModel> lst = new List<emplyeeModel>();
            foreach (var item in tbl)
            {
                emplyeeModel M1 = new emplyeeModel();
                M1.id = item.id;
                M1.name = item.name;
                M1.address = item.address;
                M1.male= item.gender;

                lst.Add(M1);

            }
            return lst;
        }
```

In the male column is a boolean and it displays a checkbox but I want to display string yes/no(True/False) instead of a checkbox, while exporting data into excel.